# create a new array that has twice the number of elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have an integer array initializer list that I want to double the length of, but assign the same elements to so that I can count the number of times 20 is in the array. The second frequency of 20 should be 4 instead of 0.
I have my original array as:
int num[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 20};

My current output is:
The frequency of 20 is :2
The frequency of 20 is :0

I tried this a couple of different ways. I tried to create the 2nd array by assigning it twice the length of the first array, but that doesn't assign the elements to the new array. I tried to Create an array of same length & copy the elements, but then I'm not sure if I can change the length of the second array and keep the same elements. I will post my code below. I know I probably have some code that is wrong, but I'm not sure how to go about this. I did comment some of it out. I originally tried to use the frequency method once instead of making a copy for the second array, but I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

```
class numCount { 
     //Method to find number of occurrences of x in num[] 
    static int frequency(int num[], int len, int x) 
    { 
        int count = 0; 
        for (int i=0; i < len; i++) 
        if (num[i] == x)  
            count++; 
        return count; 
    }//End frequency
    
    static int frequencyDbl(int newArray[], int lenNew, int y) 
    { 
        int count = 0; 
        for (int i=0; i < lenNew; i++) 
        if (newArray[i] == y)  
            count++; 
        return count; 
    }//End frequencyDbl   
    
      
    // Driver program 
    public static void main (String[] args)
    { 
          
        int num[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 20};
        int x = 20; 
        int len = num.length;
        System.out.print("The frequence of 20 is :");        
        System.out.println(frequency(num, len, x));       
        
        int [] numDbl;
        numDbl = new int [num.length];//Create array of same length
        //int z=0;
        for (int z=0; z < num.length; z++) {
            numDbl[z] = num[z];//Copy each element of the array
        }
        
        
        int newArray[] = new int[len*2];
        //copy elements of num[] to newArray[]
        
        //for (int i=0; i < num.length; i++)       
            //newArray[] = num[];
        int y = 20;        
        int lenNew = newArray.length;    
        System.out.print("The frequence of 20 is :");        
        System.out.println(frequencyDbl(newArray, lenNew, y)); 
    }//End main 
}//End numCount class
```

Comment: Why do you want to double the length of the array and populate it with two times the same data (if I read you correctly)? What's the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to create a second array that has twice as many occurrences of the number 20. The second array needs to have the same elements, just doubled. In other words, the first array has 2 occurrences of the number 20 so the second array should have 4 occurrences of the number 20.

Comment: it is an assignment from my java class. This is what I was told to do so I'm trying to learn how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code seems ok. But I can't see the moment that you copied the values from num array to newArray. Since you want to actually double the elements, like so A B C A B C, you could do something like this:

```
    for (int i=0;i<newArray.length; i++) {
           newArray[i] = num[i % len];
    }
```

The trick here is the `%` operator. You end up accessing the indexes 0...n twice. The best part is if you want to make the new array three, four or n times the size of the original array, this will always work.

As an additional piece of advice, I strongly recommend to use Java coding standards, such as:

- Class names should begin with uppercase letters (NumCount instead of numCount)
- The open brace usually is in the same line as the loop statement

Comment: The first thing I tried was to create a new array with twice as many elements, but that doesn't assign the same elements to the new array.int newArray[] = new int[len*2]; The second thing I tried was to copy the array with the same size & the same elements & just change the length of the array, but that wasnt right either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite certain if this meets your requirement but here it is.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
```

Now copy the array and double the size retaining the original contents.

```
int[] arr1 = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length*2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now, if desired, add the original array to the end of the one just created.

```
System.arraycopy(arr,0,arr1,arr.length,arr.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

These are explained at [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) and [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int%5B%5D,int))

Here is how you do it with just a simple loop.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
int[] copy = new int[arr.length*2];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     copy[i] = arr[i];
     copy[i+arr.length] = arr[i];
}   

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copy));
```

Prints

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: yes, that is basically what I'm trying to do. Then I would count the number of times a certain number is in the array which I already have. it appears there are multiple ways of doing this, which is good to know

Comment: I modified the answer to do it with just a loop in case you weren't permitted to use library methods.